# How to apply a styled class to a button but only one button can be active at any one time in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've managed to get this working to change my button class from initial to is-active, however I'd like to have multiple buttons but the is-active class should only be applied to one button at anyone time.

```
<button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 1, 'is-active': activeTab === 1}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab">BUTTON 1</button>

  activeTab: 0

  methods: {
      setActiveTab(){
        this.activeTab = 1;
      }
  }

  .is-active {
  color: blue
}

.initial {
color: red;
}
```

But would like to have:

```
<button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 1, 'is-active': activeTab === 1}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab">BUTTON 1</button>
<button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 1, 'is-active': activeTab === 1}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab">BUTTON 2</button>
<button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 1, 'is-active': activeTab === 1}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab">BUTTON 3</button>
```

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: It's better if you use v-for instead of copying your button 3 times. Makes your code cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass an id to your `setActiveTab` method

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
activeTab: 0
  },
  methods: {
      setActiveTab(id){
        this.activeTab = id;
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 1, 'is-active': activeTab === 1}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab(1)">BUTTON 1</button>
  <button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 2, 'is-active': activeTab === 2}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab(2)">BUTTON 2</button>
  <button :class="{'initial': activeTab !== 3, 'is-active': activeTab === 3}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab(3)">BUTTON 3</button>
</div>
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0bcudpw/1)

And you can tidy things a bit by using `v-for` ..

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="id in 3" :class="{'initial': activeTab !== id, 'is-active': activeTab === id}" name="button" @click="setActiveTab(id)">BUTTON {{ id }}</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c12yuoL)

Comment: Thats great. Is there away of doing this if I had different rows of buttons? So that only one button could be selected per row?

Comment: Can you show me an example fiddle/illustration of the layout you want?

Comment: eg: Row 1:  button1 BUTTON2 button3, Row 2: button4 button5 BUTTON6, Row 3: BUTTON7 button8, button9         So 1 button in each row can be selected(button selected in uppercase)

Comment: Aha, I  see. I'll do a fiddle and post it here to show you how it could be done.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is there away to do the above if I had to hard code the name of each button? eg: Row1: [apple][pear][orange], Row2: [carrot][pea][kale][sprout]?